# What are some synonyms for 'report'?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I scrutinized the [Lexico thesaurus](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/report). Nothing. I need several **neutral** synonyms for 'report' (not 'assert', 'maintain' or anything) as in 'a news article / human right organization reported that [...]' or '"Half a million children suffer from malnutrition in the country because of the conflict," the UN reported'. What are other alternatives other than simply 'say' or 'state'?

Answer (score 0):

The UN can:

announce
describe
give an account of
tell of
detail
communicate
state
divulge
disclose
reveal

Comment: None of them fits, sorry (except for 'state' which I already knew and used, I'll edit the question). I need a semantically broad neutral verb that works well with reported speech too

Comment: Yeah, none of them may "fit" because you should provide your sentence. I think you just enjoy taking the piss.

Comment: I did. 8 more to go...

Answer (score 0):

You said you already found "stated" - did you think to run that word through a thesaurus?

- stated
- declared
- asserted
- confirmed
- affirmed
- ratified

Just look at these example headlines, all from the last 48 hours:

- Dr. Sean Conley Reveals He Lied When He **Stated** Trump Was Not Put on Oxygen Friday
- Toronto had more COVID-19 cases than previously **stated** as Ontario reports 735
- Trump **Declares** 'I Get It,' Then Briefly Leaves Hospital to Salute Supporters
- Mbali Ntuli **asserts** intention to lead the DA

Comment: They don't fit. They are too narrow, semantically. Please check my examples

Comment: I think this is just game playing and I am getting annoyed by questions from Sergey. Everyone honestly tries to provide solutions, and he spends all his time saying why no answer is adequate. And he refuses to actually put up the sentence he is "trying" to write. So, I will no longer be answering his questions.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You're wrong, Sergey. Most of the words in my list would fit in your example sentence **and** are commonly used by news media. Why even ask native English speakers for help and then not accept their answers?

Comment: @Astralbee "Say something in a solemn and emphatic manner" (Lexico). That's what 'declare' is. "State a fact or belief confidently and forcefully" (ibid). That's what 'assert' is. As I said, I need a semantically broad and neutral synonym. I'm sorry, but your examples are simply not applicable

Comment: I asked him the same thing. Why bother....

Answer (score 0):

Although this is just avoiding the issue I would rewrite the sentence.

> According to the United Nations half a million children suffer from malnutrition

If you want to leave it as it is then *claimed* is neutral as to the speaker's view of the truth value of the claim although it might not be neutral enough for you. Another option might be *noted* which seems to me quite neutral.

Comment: 'Claim' implies that it's baseless or, at least, not a conclusion of some authoritative analysis/research